# Sum / Count Distinct is not returning correctly

Tags: sql-server

I can return 84 rows with my select distinct on my "ub.Id" column.

When I count distinct or sum conditionally on that column the value returned is incorrect.

I know there are topics on this question, but I can't find a solution and I must be missing something.  It looks straight forward to me.  84 rows returned, but I must be missing a group or something else and I've played with it a ton.

Focus is on the last 3 columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.Organization_Name,
    ui.DisplayName, 
    ui.NumLogins, 
    COUNT(uw.Title) Assigned,
    SUM(CASE WHEN uw.Status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NotStarted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN uw.Status = 'incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InProgress,
    SUM(CASE WHEN uw.grade >=80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ub.Id) ShouldBe84a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ub.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ShouldBe84b,
    ub.Id
FROM @Organizations o
INNER JOIN @UserInfo ui on ui.OrgId = o.OrgId
LEFT JOIN @UserWorkshop uw on uw.UserId = ui.UserId
LEFT JOIN @UserBehavior ub on ub.UserId = ui.UserId
WHERE username = 'user@email.com'
AND ub.Id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY o.Organization_Name,
        ui.DisplayName,
        ui.NumLogins, 
        ub.id;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Boyd

**EDIT Resolved  Thanks for the help, pointed me in the right direction*

Resolved code:

```
select o.Organization_Name,ui.DisplayName, ui.NumLogins, 
count(distinct case when uw.Title Is Not Null then uw.Title else null end) Assigned,
count(distinct case when uw.Status Is Null then uw.Title else null end) NotStarted,
count(distinct case when uw.Status = 'incomplete' then uw.Title else null end) InProgress,
count(distinct case when uw.grade >=80 then uw.Grade else null end) Completed,
count(distinct case when ub.CaseStatus = 1 then ub.Id else null end) CasesSupported,
count(distinct case when ub.CaseOwnerId = ui.UserId then ub.Id else null end) CasesOwned
from @Organizations o
inner join @UserInfo ui on ui.OrgId = o.OrgId
left join @UserWorkshop uw on uw.UserId = ui.UserId
left join @UserBehavior ub on ub.UserId = ui.UserId
--left join @UserBehaviorDetails ubd on (ubd.Id=ub.Id and ubd.UserId=ub.UserId)
where username = 'user@email.com'
and ub.Id is not null
group by o.Organization_Name,ui.DisplayName,ui.NumLogins
```

Comment: Use of first DISTINCT after the SELECT statement is not necessary as GROUP BY doing this itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're counting distinct values for `ub.Id`, but you're also grouping by the same column.

You need to remove `ub.Id` from the column list and the GROUP BY to get your aggregates correct. You also don't need DISTINCT when using GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
    o.Organization_Name,
    ui.DisplayName, 
    ui.NumLogins, 
    COUNT(uw.Title) Assigned,
    SUM(CASE WHEN uw.Status IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NotStarted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN uw.Status = 'incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) InProgress,
    SUM(CASE WHEN uw.grade >=80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ub.Id) ShouldBe84a,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ub.Id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ShouldBe84b
FROM @Organizations o
INNER JOIN @UserInfo ui on ui.OrgId = o.OrgId
LEFT JOIN @UserWorkshop uw on uw.UserId = ui.UserId
LEFT JOIN @UserBehavior ub on ub.UserId = ui.UserId
WHERE username = 'user@email.com'
AND ub.Id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY o.Organization_Name,
        ui.DisplayName,
        ui.NumLogins;
```